# Shifting Figure to the Left in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, horizontal-alignment

I have a figure in a .pdf file that I'd like to shift to the left a little bit in how it appears in the slide.  How may I do this?

```
\frame
 { 
 \frametitle{Slide Title}
  \vspace{-0.75cm} 
   \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width = 12.25cm]{PicTitle.pdf}
   \end{center}
 }
```

Comment: I'd note that there are technical reasons to prefer `\begin{frame} ... \end{frame}` over `\frame{...}` (nothing directly to do with the question in hand, but a general `beamer` comment).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could try putting some space to the right of the figure.

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width = 12.25cm]{PicTitle.pdf} \hspace*{4cm}
\end{center}
```

Just change the '4cm' as appropriate to get the effect you need.

Comment: Ian's answer helped tremendously, but didn't quite hit the nail on the coffin. See the following difference in the hspace. `\frame { \frametitle{Slide Title} \begin{center} \hspace*{-0.35cm}\includegraphics[width = 12.75cm]{Pic.pdf} \end{center} }`

Answer (score 17):

Here are a number of ways of positioning elements horizontally within a `frame`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\theimage}{\includegraphics[width=15mm]{tiger}}% Shorthand
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \hspace*{\fill}\theimage\hspace*{\fill}

  \hspace*{\fill}\hspace*{\fill}\theimage\hspace*{\fill}

  \hspace*{4cm}\theimage

  \hspace*{\fill}\theimage\hspace*{4cm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

From top to bottom the displacement represents:

1. Horizontally centred - similar to

   ```
   \centerline{\theimage}
   ```

   or

   ```
   \begin{center}
     \theimage
   \end{center}
   ```
2. Horizontally positioned at with a ratio of 2:1 whitespace on either side (stemming from two `\fill`s on the left and one on the right of `\theimage`). Other combinations will, of course, imply other ratios;
3. Shifted a fixed length (`4cm` in the example) from the left margin;
4. Shifted a fixed length (`4cm` in the example) from the right margin.

The use of `\fill` allows for something that has infinite stretch, while the starred version of `\hspace` is sometimes preferred when setting space from the text block boundaries inward.

In a similar way, adding a length `<len>` on one side within a centred image (say, left), pushes it away from that side (to the right) by half that distance (or `.5<len>`), as in @IanThompson's answer.