# How to smoothly translate a figure as an animation in the same slide?

Tags: beamer, slideshow, transition

I do not know how to appropriately describes this kind of feature in beamer.

I'm watching some presentations on youtube and I'm interested in how this presenter is transitioning the figure in this presentation that makes room for the text to appear:
https://youtu.be/qEAIJXxd0nQ?t=12m20s

I know you can make unique slide transitions in beamer, but how is one able to smoothly move figures as an animation to the side of the same slide?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shifting Figure to the Left in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44322/shifting-figure-to-the-left-in-beamer)

Comment: @Georges I don't think so. That is just off centering the figure in a static slide. I'm referring to an animation as the one in the video I have linked.

Comment: `\transreplace` with ~30 frames. Just like the old school animation.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366884/36296 could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With slide transitions one could create a similar effect:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\transwipe<1-3>[direction=0]

\begin{onlyenv}<1>
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{figure}
\end{onlyenv}

\begin{onlyenv}<2->
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.7\textwidth}
            \centering  
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}<3->{.25\textwidth}
            text text text text text
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{onlyenv}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```